Cosine Sum to Product Derivation Question
Question Overview
I was wondering if the order you subtract $\cos(x) - \cos(y)$ in matters when deriving the cosine difference formulas. This is asked out of my curiosity (no textbook, etc.) because I found that the details of my problem contradict subtraction’s non-commutative property, but also cannot figure why my reasoning is false. This may be relevant to future explanations and or teachings of this product to sum formula.
My reasoning and problem, no success in finding a solution thus far:
In the derivation of the cosine difference (sum) to product identities
$$\begin{align}
\cos(x) - \cos(y) &= -2\sin\left[\frac{x + y}{2}\right]\sin\left[\frac{x - y}{2}\right] \tag1 \\[4pt]
\cos(y) - \cos(x) &= \phantom{-}2\sin\left[\frac{x + y}{2}\right]\sin\left[\frac{-x + y}{2}\right] \tag2
\end{align}$$
because they are still equivalent expressions after deriving both ways, does this mean you can subtract $\cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(\alpha + \beta)$ for the latter or $\cos(\alpha + \beta) - \cos(\alpha - \beta)$ for the former and still get the same sum to product equation for cosine? This also interestingly implies $\cos(\alpha+\beta) - \cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(\alpha + \beta)$ which isn’t right. I have not found a way to disprove something here yet.
May someone help?
Thank you for your time and understanding my inaptitude.

Are you the same person who asked this question?

No. Similar idea though

(Using eqn numbers I added.) In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ on the left, there are two strategies: (a) swap $x$ & $y$, reversing the subtraction (changing nothing else, including the "$-$" on the right) to get $$\cos y-\cos x=-2\sin\frac12(y+x)\sin\frac12(y-x)\tag{2.a}$$ or (b) multiply by $-1$ (changing nothing else, including the order of $x$ & $y$): $$-\cos x+\cos y=+2\sin\frac12(x+y)\sin\frac12(x-y)\tag{2.b}$$ As $\sin(-z)=-\sin z$, these relations are equivalent; but neither matches your $(2)$, where on the RHS you've done both (a) & (b), canceling their effects to get $(1)$'s RHS again.

Maybe you should show your derivation in full. Because the linked derivation by @ConMan is different from what you stated. Note the LHS in the linked derivation is identical in both expressions, but opposite in order in yours.

@Blue   I see, thank you for clearing it up.  I was wondering if there is a reason why cos(y) has to be subtracted from cos(x) in the derivation of this sum to product formula.  In other words, what is stopping the variant of the formula derived from cos(y) - cos(x) from being correct?  Again, thank you.

@JokeHang: Writing $x=p-q$ and $y=p+q$ gives $\cos x-\cos y=\cos(p-q)-\cos(p+q)$, which expands as
$$(\cos p \cos q+\sin p\sin q)-(\cos p\cos q-\sin p\sin q) = \phantom{-}2\sin p\sin q \tag1$$ Reversing the subtraction to $\cos y-\cos x=\cos(p+q)-\cos(p-q)$ gives
$$(\cos p \cos q-\sin p\sin q)-(\cos p\cos q+\sin p\sin q) = -2\sin p\sin q \tag2$$ with the expected sign change. Somewhere, your own thinking on the derivation introduces an additional sign change that cancels-out the expected effect. (Eg, reversing the subtraction and re-assigning $x=p+q$ and $y=p-q$ simply reiterates $(1)$.)
